Fill in missing values in summarized dataframe in R
I have a sorted, summarized (unsure of the correct terminology) dataframe where rows/ranks with triplicated count values have been removed, leaving just the first and last instance of that count value. I would like to regenerate the intervening rows. Here is some toy data:
df_have <- data.frame(rank = c(1,2,3,5,6,7,9,10), count = c(10,9,8,8,7,5,5,3))
df_have
  rank count
1    1    10
2    2     9
3    3     8
4    5     8
5    6     7
6    7     5
7    9     5
8   10     3

df_want <- data.frame(rank = c(1:10), count = c(10,9,8,8,8,7,5,5,5,3))
df_want
   rank count
1     1    10
2     2     9
3     3     8
4     4     8
5     5     8
6     6     7
7     7     5
8     8     5
9     9     5
10   10     3

Is there a simple way to do this? Thanks!

library(tidyr)
df_have |>
  complete(rank = seq(min(rank), max(rank))) |>
  fill(count)


    rank count
   <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1    10
 2     2     9
 3     3     8
 4     4     8
 5     5     8
 6     6     7
 7     7     5
 8     8     5
 9     9     5
10    10     3

